# Making a loop over an array and only add even numbers to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

The idea of the program is to make a loop that will iterate over the option elements in the select box and only add even numbers to it (from 16 to 30 including 30).
To be specific : It is a fontSizeBox and I want to add font sizes to it so the user can choose from them .

The problem is that I get numbers starting from 16 to 23 and not as expected .
The code :

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let fontSizeBox = document.createElement("select");
  fontSizeBox.name = "fontSize-box";
  document.body.prepend(fontSizeBox);

  let fontSizeBoxLabel = document.createElement("label");
  fontSizeBoxLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Choose the font size :"));
  fontSizeBox.before(fontSizeBoxLabel);

  for (let i = 16; i <= 30; i += 2) {
    fontSizeBox.appendChild(document.createElement("option"));
  }
  
  Array.from(fontSizeBox);
  /* The above code will make the fontSizeBox an array so I can iterate over
  it using the loop */
  for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    fontSizeBox[i].innerHTML = i + 16;
    /* The following code won't work without the number constructor 
    because I tried this code in the console and here is the output: 

    typeof fontSizeBox[0].innerHTML;
    >> 'string' */
    if ((Number(fontSizeBox[i].innerHTML) % 2) !== 0) {
      continue;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<title>Document</title>
```

Comment: Why do you need the second loop? Just add the innerHTML in the first loop: `var element = document.createElement("option"); element.innerHTML = i; fontSizeBox.appendChild(element);` And remove all the code below that.

Comment: Also, `Array.from(fontSizeBox)` does not convert the `fontSizeBox` to an array. It *returns* an array which you need to assign to another variable: `var fontSizeBoxArray = Array.from(fontSizeBox)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do it for you?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",`<label>Choose the font size: <select name="fontSize-box">${[...Array(8)].map((_,i)=>`<option>${2*i+16}</option>`).join("")}</select></label>`);
}
```

```html
<title>Document</title>
```

I decided to use `.insertAdjacentHTML()`, and only *once*, as every modification of the DOM will be costly in terms of browser activity. While the `.createElement()` and `.appendChild()` calls are fast and efficient in themselves, doing everything in one go will probably be more efficient in the end than the multiple create and append actions.